# How to using global variable robotframework?

Tags: robotframework, selenium2library

I want to increase my variable through loop. How and where can I declare it (such as: `{myvar} = 0)`

```
*** Test Cases ***

Start to Login
    Log     ${myvar}

*** Keywords ***

Start to Login
    [Arguments]    ${LIST}
    : FOR    ${LINE}    IN    @{LIST}
    \    ${myvar}=    Evaluate    ${myvar} + 1
    \    Log    ${myvar}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to the answer from @pankaj-mishra is the following. This removes the `evaluate` and uses `Set Variable` with [simple arithmetics](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#advanced-variable-features) to increase the value. It is important to start with a numerical value. This is why the variable is created with ${0} to ensure that the `0` is [indeed a number](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#number-variables) and not a string.

```
*** Test Cases ***
test counter
    ${counter}    Set Variable     ${0}

    :FOR    ${item}    IN RANGE    10
    \    ${counter}    Set Variable    ${counter+1}
    \    Log    ${counter}
```

Answer (score 1):

have a look on this

```
*** Settings ***

*** Variables ***
@{LIST}    5    6    7
${myvar}

*** Test Cases ***
Check
    Start to Login    ${LIST}


*** Keywords ***
Start to Login
    [Arguments]    ${LIST}
    :FOR    ${LINE}    IN    @{LIST}
    \    ${myvar}=    Evaluate    ${myvar} + 1
    \    Log to console    ${myvar}
```

output

```
Check                                                                 
  1
  2
  3
```

Comment: I tried your way, but I got an error if declare variable ${myvar} without value. If I set ${myvar} = 0 first, then in loop, it print 1 all repeat

Comment: can you share your log.xml  when you are getting this error?

Comment: RIDE alert "ERROR: Data sanity check failed ! Reset change ?"

Comment: there must be an log.HTML generated when u run the code..can you share that..the error u posted did not helped

Comment: I changed your declaration to: ${myvar}  0. And it is ok now. thanks